# Can anyone explain what this ember-cli error means?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-cli

I just updated my app to Ember-CLI 0.0.42 and Ember 1.7.0, using "ember init". Now, i'm getting the following error when I run "ember server":

```
    version: 0.0.42
    Livereload server on port 35729
    Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200
    Command failed:
    Error: Command failed:
     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
     at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
     at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I have *literally* no idea where this error could be coming from, and everything was working until I went to update my packages and so on. I've tried redoing the updates, I've rolled back from my previous commit, all for naught.

ANY help would be *extremely* appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: do `ember server --verbose`

Comment: That is with the --verbose flag. Which is what is especially maddening.

Comment: make sure different server is not running, try with different host, and port.

Comment: Didn't change it in any way.

Comment: Are you using `ember-cli-compass-compiler`? I get this (helpful) error when my scss is invalid, specifically when I used `@include display-flex` without first `@import "compass/css3/flexbox"` (compass 1.0.1). Or event missing a `;` from the end of a line in a `scss` file.

Comment: Ultimately, there was a conflict between broccoli-compass and ember-cli-compass-compiler. Somehow broccoli-compass got installed independent of ember-cli-compass-compiler. I uninstalled both, then reinstalled ember-cli-compass-compiler, and it worked. 

Regardless, it's not a super-helpful error message. I spent half a day tracking this down after I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Sass error - the latest update to ember-cli-compass-compiler made the exposed the error in the output.

Comment: Yes, it was a conflict of broccoli-compass and ember-cli-compass-compiler. I uninstalled both then reinstalled ember-cli-compass-compiler and it fixed itself.